# TypeScript cannot find name IPromise in RxJS definition

Tags: typescript, rxjs

I'm using `typings` to import type definitions and `gulp-typescript` to run the TypeScript compiler. When I run my TypeScript task, I get a few warnings about the `IPromise` and `IDisposable` types used in the RxJS typings:

```
typings/main/ambient/rx/index.d.ts(34,20): error TS2304: Cannot find name 'IPromise'.
typings/main/ambient/rx/index.d.ts(36,29): error TS2304: Cannot find name 'IPromise'.
typings/main/ambient/rx/index.d.ts(49,36): error TS2304: Cannot find name 'IDisposable'.
typings/main/ambient/rx/index.d.ts(51,22): error TS2304: Cannot find name 'IPromise'.
typings/main/ambient/rx/index.d.ts(53,19): error TS2304: Cannot find name 'IPromise'.
typings/main/ambient/rx/index.d.ts(55,36): error TS2304: Cannot find name 'IPromise'.
typings/main/ambient/rx/index.d.ts(57,33): error TS2304: Cannot find name 'IPromise'.
```

I'm assuming there is another typings library that RxJS depends on, but none was specified when I installed the definition. I added the RxJS typings with

```
typings install --save --ambient rx
```

The comment at the beginning of the installed file, `rx/index.d.ts`, says it's for RxJS v2.5.3, even though RxJS is up to version 4 now. But the library was updated last year, according to the `typings search --ambient rx`, so I'm assuming it's just that comment that is outdated.

What other type definition do I need and is there some other way I could have found it than to just ask here?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

The RxJS type definition from DefinitelyTyped does appear to be outdated. Instead, use the type definition provided by the npm package.

```
typings install --save --ambient npm:rx/ts/rx.all.d.ts
```

**Update** For typings >= 1.0, use `--global` instead.

```
typings install --save --global npm:rx/ts/rx.all.d.ts
```

Comment: This should get a lot more upvotes (even though it's not --ambient anymore - it's --global).

When searching for typings using `typings search rx`, all I see is DefinitelyTyped as source - why is not npm in the results?

Comment: Thanks for the notice, I updated the answer to reflect the changed command line argument. I have little luck with `typings search`. Hopefully it's something they're working on.